# Customize Android Progressbar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am trying to customize the android progress bar. Here is a rough idea of what I am going to do.

1. I have files that are broken into small packets, I am playing them one after the other.
2. All files will be mapped sequentially .Say 30 mins files is divided into files of 2 mins,3mins or any random value of mins
3. The entire progress bar will be mapped for 30 mins, I need to map the packet of data with a particular color, its previous with one color and its next with other color.
4. Upon clicking a  particular location of the progress bar, the file that is be identified.
5. A small hairline type marker that shows the starting/ending point of each packet.

I am planning to use `progressBar` for this purpose.

Any sort of input,approach most appreciable.